# "Combine latest" with ReactiveCocoa and signal of signals

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

What's the best approach for implementing "combine latest" for signal of signals in ReactiveCocoa? I have the following problem:

Given N text fields, subscribe to the `UIControlEditingEventChanged` event, and create a new signal based on the values that get called. The subscription is done once per subscriber and the values are then used in conjunction with one another. So here's what I've got:

```
__block NSMutableSet *subscriptions = [NSMutableSet set];
RACSignal *validationSignals = [[[[TEXT_FIELDS rac_sequence].signal flattenMap:^RACStream* (UITextField *textField) {
    return [textField rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(UITextField* textField) {
    if(![subscriptions containsObject:textField]) {
         [subscriptions addObject:textField];
        return [textField rac_validationSignal];
    }
    return [RACSignal empty];
}]];
```

Where `rac_validationSignal` is my own class handling validation of UITextFields. The signals get through correctly, but only one at a time. I'd need the value of all subscriptions at once, in order to get the validity of all fields that are edited.

EDIT:

One possible solution involves a mutable array that I add the new field to and send the combination signal as I would normally. This seems quite good, any other ideas?

```
__block NSMutableSet *subscriptions = [NSMutableSet set];
__block NSMutableArray *signals = [NSMutableArray array];
RAC(self.editButton, enabled) =
[[[[TEXT_FIELDS rac_sequence].signal flattenMap:^RACStream* (UITextField *textField) {
    return [textField rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(UITextField* textField) {
    if(![subscriptions containsObject:textField]) {
        [subscriptions addObject:textField];
        [signals addObject:[textField rac_validationSignal]];
        return [RACSignal combineLatest:signals];
    }
    return [RACSignal empty];
}] map:^NSNumber *(RACTuple *value) {
    for(NSNumber *isValid in value) {
        if(![isValid boolValue]) { return @(NO); }
    }
return @(YES);
}];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
NSArray *TEXT_FIELDS = @[[txt1.rac_textSignal distinctUntilChanged],[txt2.rac_textSignal distinctUntilChanged]];
[[RACSignal combineLastest:TEXT_FIELDS reduce:^ (NSSTring *txt1, NSString *txt2) {
    // Return your validate method here
    // Signal only send `next` value it is different from previous `next` value 
    return [self inputvalication];
}] setKeyPath:@"enabled" onObject:self.myButton];
```

Comment: This does not do the same thing as I was looking for. The `combineLatest` takes in a "static" array of signals. I was interested in a dynamic array that gets updated every time user types in a field. See my sample solution for a working example of what I was looking for.

Comment: @MikkoHarju, sorry I still don't get it, `rac_textSignal` get updated everytime user types in a field as well, it's not static.

Comment: If I should create an array from all of my text fields and run  `combineLatest` on them the signal will contain the content of all of them and depending on where I am subscribing to the `rac_textSignal` it may return empty strings or actual values on the fields.

I am only interested in the ones that were actually modified by the user. That is why I am subscribing only after a `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event is triggered for a given field.

Comment: how about `- (RACSignal *)distinctUntilChanged`, it sendsonly `next`s for which -isEqual: returns NO when compared to the previous `next`.

Comment: I just modified my answer, hope it helps. And don't forget `-filter` which you can filter the signal value and add it to your desired mutable array.